# API is not receiving my access token

Tags: vue.js, axios

```
fetchData () {
  axios.get('https://some-address.com/orders', {
    params: {
      limit: this.limit,
      offset: this.offset
    },
    headers: auth.getAuthHeader()
  })
    .then((resp) => {
      this.req = resp.data
      console.log(resp)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Storing token in "auth/index.js"

```
  // The object to be passed as a header for authenticated requests
  getAuthHeader () {
    return {
      'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    }
  }
```

When i send GET request to receive a list of items, i'm getting the following headers in response:

[image]

in request:

[image]

Status code 403, obviously API is not getting my `access_token`. But if i make the same request in Postman (manually pasting access token value) - it works.

Error from console:

[image]

Comment: The response/request you've shown looks like a CORS preflight request, which will be made by the browser automatically (this doesn't happen when using Postman). Your server shouldn't 403 for a preflight request, so I suggest looking into that.

Comment: @KirkLarkin so it's an issue on API side?

Comment: I can't be sure - Can you confirm that it's the `OPTIONS` request that is giving a 403?

Comment: I'm sending token in Authorization header from options.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of that?

Comment: Added to a main post.

Comment: Ok, so your update confirms that the server is behaving badly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966434/response-for-preflight-403-forbidden) might help confirm what I've said so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed issue on the backend side, thanks to @KirkLarkin, he pointed me in the right direction. I had to coordinate with backend developer for making correct headers for CORS requests.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining headers before:

```js
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'Authorization' : localStorage.getItem('access_token')
};
```

Comment: I've already tried `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('access_token')` above `fetchData ()` in my case. No effect :(

Comment: Use axios interceptor for request and check if the Authorization is present in the headers before the request is made https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors