# Report a bug or not

Tags: web

I am able to bypass 403 page using OPTIONS request method and getting 200 OK response.
The page is an assets/css folder.
Is it a bug or not that I can report to website? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "bypass", and whether you are able unexpectedly extract any sensitive information (that should have been protected by authorization) via the `OPTIONS` request.

In general, it is normal to render a 2XX response to a preflight (`OPTIONS`) request if the page in question is marked as allowed for cross-origin access. See also answers in: [Response for preflight 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966434/response-for-preflight-403-forbidden/44968217#44968217).

The principal difference here is that if you get an error response for `OPTIONS`, a cross-origin request from the browser wouldn't even be able to find out that 403; it wouldn't even be performed if the preflight failed.

TL;DR most probably not a bug, working as intended.